# Converting .ovf file to .vtk file or vts file

Tags: vtk, ovf

How can I convert a .ovf file to .vtk file or vts file to view an image in paraview?

I tried with these commands but these didn't work

```
.\mumax3-convert.exe -vtk="ascii" D:\Mumax3\Data\filename.out\m*.ovf
.\mumax3-convert.exe -vtk=binary D:\Mumax3\Data\filename.out\m*.ovf
```